# How to combine results from a suspend function and a flow in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-flow, suspend

Guys imagine I have these two sources of data:

```
val flowA: Flow<String>
suspend fun funB(): Int
```

How can I combine the result of both into a flow (let's say `Flow<Pair<String, Int>>`)?

How about the approach below? Is there a better way?

```
combine(
  flowA,
  flow {emit(funB())}
) { a, b ->
  ...
}
```

Comment: You want to put that same Int with all the strings in flow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want the same `Int` paired with each String in `flowA`, you can do it as follows:

```kotlin
val funBResult = funB()
val pairs = flowA.map { it to funBResult }
```

If `funB()` is in fact a function that takes the `String` as a parameter, you could do something like:

```kotlin
val pairs = flowA.map { it to funB(it) }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the second line will not start before the first completes resulting in unnecessary delays, especially if the source of data is linked to a network call. Isn't the approach suggested by the question itself better?